# How can I query all user folders within OneDrive (via Microsoft Graph) without requiring User ID or User Principal Name?

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to create a broad search of our Company OneDrive but I need to do so without targeting a specific User.  I have to search files for specific contents so I need to cast a wide net.

I have 2 separate API integrations with Sharepoint and OneDrive.
I've tested both GET and POST calls to find a specific file located in my personal OneDrive Folder.

I've created 3 identical Excel files but named them differently.

| File Name | File Location |
| --- | --- |
| Test File 1 | https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/sites/SHAREPOINTSITE/Shared |
| Test File 2 | https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/sites/SHAREPOINTSITE/Shared |
| Test File 3 | https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/personal/EMPLOYEE_ID/documents/documents |

Knowing only the **searchQuery**, I tried this POST call **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query** with the following payload response but the result only locates ***Test File 1*** and ***Test File 2***.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "driveItem"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "${(event.payload.request.email)!}"
      },
      "region": "US"
    }
  ]
}
```

Knowing the **searchQuery** along with the **userPrincipalName**, I was able to successfully execute this GET call to locate ***Test File 3*** on my personal Company OneDrive.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/drive/root/search(q='{searchQuery')?select=name,id,webUrl](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserPrincipalName%7D/drive/root/search(q=%27%7BsearchQuery%27)?select=name,id,webUrl)

Is there any way to perform the same function without /users/{userPrincipalName/ ?

Cheers,

R

Answer (score 0):

List children of a DriveItem or folder with a known path instead of user id:

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/children
```

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#list-children-of-a-driveitem-with-a-known-path

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.  Do you know if this approach would help query all users within the Organization (all users' personal OneDrive folders)?

Comment: Not sure but i think this will work within the organization

Comment: The problem that I found yesterday is that personal folders all have a different DriveID but from what I can see they all begin with the same 2 characters. "b!"  I'm tried applying query parameters to expand the search but I can't get a successful result.